# Phone won't reflash or won't let me install a rom (Galaxy S5)

Tags: rom-flashing

I forgot the password to my phone, and I didn't have anyway to restore it, so I tried to do a factory wipe, but it made my phone stuck in a bootloop (with the samsung logo), and the thing is -
I tried to reflash the phone, and even tried to make a firmware upgrade and initialisation, but the phone won't let me do so. I finish downloading, everything is fine, the phone starts to install the firmware or something (it's has a loading bar and says install... charging... and then it says erases and everything is the same again).
I got it in a video so you can see it clearly and understand what I mean:
https://youtu.be/QxZ-mEo4sRg
so, what should I do in order to not let the phone erase upgrade or reflash I am trying to do.
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can acces the **Recovery Mode** and acces the storage via usb, you can try to flash a new rom, like a **Custom Rom**. You can search online, there are plenty of them. Or if you do not stole that phone, you can contact Samsung Support, i'am sure that it's gonna be helpful.